# Can I safely delete C:\ProgramData\Adobe\CameraRaw?

Tags: adobe-camera-raw

I am uncertain what this folder is or does. But I have never deliberately moved or saved anything there. Can I delete this folder harmlessly?

How can I stop Adobe from respawning this folder? As you can see, I need more free space on C:!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvqfi.jpg

Comment: Randomly selecting application directories for deletion is a sure way to create problems for yourself. Here are some [tips to free up space from Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/tips-to-free-up-drive-space-on-your-pc-4d97fc4a-0175-8d49-ac2f-bcf27de46d34). Failing that, buy more storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you record/edit raw files in any Adobe product (Bridge/Lightroom/Photoshop) Camera Raw is the engine being used. If you delete it you will not be able to edit raw files with any of those programs.

Comment: AFAIK Lightroom do not store RAW module on the same place and do not use (in general) PS CameraRAW. LR store it in `C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Lightroom Classic\Resources\Settings\Adobe\Profiles` (Windows)

Comment: It is used by all Adobe program that can open a raw file... it is the "camera support" and demosaicing function. The list of programs that require it from adobe is "*Supported applications include Photoshop, Lightroom Classic, Lightroom, Photoshop Elements, After Effects, and Bridge*." https://helpx.adobe.com/camera-raw/kb/camera-raw-plug-supported-cameras.html

Comment: I mean this instance, pointed by OP

Answer (score 1):

IF you use Photoshop and CameraRAW plugin don't. This folder contain the camera-lens profiles to correct lens distortions.

If you delete it I am not sure you can use CameraRAW at all. Or if you can you will not be able to do lens correction.

Answer (score 1):

It's unwise to delete the folder, but you can delete all profiles inside the folder from cameras and lenses you don't own/want to edit. that's what i did. it saves quite a lot of space.